# Doctrine2 (Entity vs Repository)

Tags: model-view-controller, model, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm new using Doctrine2, where is the best place to write my custom function in the Entities or in the Repositories? let's say I have an User entity and I want to get his age.

If I put the function getAge in my entity is very straight forward. But if I put the function getAge in my repository I have to pass the userId to get the age of that user. am I wrong? what is the best approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally when working with entities, you'll want to keep all data and operations on an entity in the entity itself, while repositories are only used for *fetching the correct entity to begin with*.

As an example, `getAge()` and `setAge()` return/operate on data in a single entity, so they should go in the entity itself, while a theoretical `getUsersByAge()` that locates all users of a specific age would go in the repository.

Comment: How do I access the entity manager from an entity? do I have to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: You don't. Your entities should not be aware of the EntityManager.

Comment: why is that the entity should not be aware of the EntityManager? please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be helpful

```
$em = Zend_Registry::getInstance ()->entitymanager;
$user = $em->getRepository('Model_User')->findOneBy(array( 'user_id' => $userID,
        ));
$user->getAge();
```